# passing high resolution images from one activity to other

Tags: android

I'm creating an image filter app in Android studio. first, the user selects an image from gallery and it will be displayed in imageview. Then the user clicks edit button and that image is displayed in imageview of next activity where we can add filters... It works fine with low resolution images but when I select any high resolution image it is shown in first imageview but when I click edit button either the app crashes or the last image I had selected is displayed.I searched for the solution but couldn't find it. If anyone knows how to solve this problem please help me

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to the size of data that can be passed through an intent. The limit is [roughly 500Kb](https://www.neotechsoftware.com/blog/android-intent-size-limit) - your high resolution photographs will be larger than this.

Consider saving your image to a file location on the device, passing the URI to the receiving activity and loading it within there.

Answer (score 0):

first paste crash logs.
then instead of passing image itself just pass image path.
or simply add the edit tools and mainView in one activity and make edit tools invisible! however you can use fragment too.

Answer (score 0):

> use with putExtra to send the Uri Path:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent .setClass(ThisActivity.this,  NewActivity.class);
            intent .putExtra("KEY", Uri);
            startActivity(intent );
```

You just need to add path of image.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to save the image in storage and pass the Uri of location instead of passing the image.

Save image in storage:-

```
public static Uri saveImageOnExternalStorage(Bitmap capturedBitmap, String imageId) {
    if (null != capturedBitmap ) {

        OutputStream fOutputStream;

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File file = new File(path + "temp", mediaId + ".png");
        file.delete();
        if (!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        try {
            if (file.createNewFile()) {
                fOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                capturedBitmap.compress(COMPRESS_FORMAT, 100, fOutputStream);

                fOutputStream.flush();
                fOutputStream.close();

                return Uri.fromFile(file); // return saved image path on external storage
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now the same Uri you can pass in the intent of next activity:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,  LaunchActivity.class);
            intent .putExtra("image_key", Uri);
            startActivity(intent );
```